# Python3: Scapy attribute IP needs ip4 address as parameter, but I just have the url

Tags: python-3.x, url, ip, scapy, converters

I've built a webcrawler that uses the HTMLParser lib in Python. It goes on a page, and continues with the next one, linked on the loaded page, etc. It just collects the links. Now I need to protocoll the TCP/IP traffic between the hosts and my PC (packet sniffing). The result should be stored in a file.pcap. I've found an' example that seems to be useful for my purpose. Am I right?

[reference code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868698/creating-a-pcap-file-using-python/49228605#49228605)!

Here the code of the answer I'm interested in:

```
from scapy.all import wrpcap, Ether, IP, UDP
packet = Ether() / IP(dst="1.2.3.4") / UDP(dport=123)
wrpcap('foo.pcap', [packet])
```

1. Can this code be used for it? 2. If yes, how? 3. As parameters I've just the hostnames, but not ***dst(ip4-address)*** and the ***dport***-data. It seems clear that ***1.2.3.4*** and ***123*** are just dummies to give an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are very unaware of what an IP or a port mean. You should start by reading articles about that.

http://mason.gmu.edu/~afinn/html/tele/components/urls_ip.htm
https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/TCP-IP

Once this is done, have a read at the documentation to start with Scapy:
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Also: **what is your question?**

Do you want to :

- Ping ? `sr1(IP(dst="www.google.com")/ICMP())`
- connect ? (TCP_client in https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/http.html)
- ...?

Comment: Thanks. Your links are very useful. I will reedit the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Scapy, but I know how to get IP by addresses, **you can `ping` it**:

```sh
$ ping stackoverflow.com
PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.193.69): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=0 ttl=46 time=374.685 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=397.401 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=684.908 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 time=301.389 ms
```

then you will know that stackoverflow.com's IP is 151.101.193.69

Comment: I don't know how this makes any sense. OP asked about the TCP ports, but obviously there are no ports in ICMP... -_-

Comment: Yes it makes. There are 2 questions: One about url to ip conversion and a second is if there is a similar function as wrcap that takes an url as parameter. wrcap needs the IP and the port. Now meanwhile I've red  a little bit and now I know that for http port 80 is the default and for https its 443, when I'm not wrong.