# Pylibpcap for python-3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pcap, libpcap, packet-capture

There was a library `pylibpcap` for python2 that contained the functionality to create pcap objects like this:

```py
import pcap

pc = pcap.pcapObject()
```

Now I'm looking for an analogue for python3, but from what I found (`pypcap`, `pcap-ct`), these libraries don't contain similar functionality and look completely different. So maybe someone knows how the `pylibpcap` library can be replaced in python3? I will be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this package similar to your requirement, installation steps mentioned below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
$ pip3 install Cython python-libpcap
```

And usage as below:

```
from pylibpcap import OpenPcap
p = OpenPcap("pcap.pcap", "a")
p.write(buf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store pcap files in python using scapy module. install it by -

```
pip install scapy
```

You can store the network traffic in pcap files using scapy. More info at this link - [creating a pcap file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868698/creating-a-pcap-file-using-python)

Comment: While it is viable for some applications, I have found that scapy only lets you process around 1000 packets per second, which in modern times is painfully slow. The more native the binding, the better for performance.

The scapy implementation is also documented badly.